# Android: get a feedback when trying to connect to a wifi spot

Tags: java, android

I am working on an android application in which i have created a list with WiFi spots and under them two fields(ssid field and a password field) and a connect button. 
[the app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woHR0.png)

My problem is, when i fill up the 2 fields and click the connect button, i want to take a feedback if the phone connect to the wifi spot that i am trying to, or if the password is wrong. So that i can print a toast if it was connected or entered the wrong password.

**when the password is wrong, phone connect instantly to the previous wifi spot.

the code i use when the button pressed

```
 WifiConfiguration wifiConfiguration = new WifiConfiguration();
 wifiConfiguration.SSID = "\""+ ssidField.getText().toString() +"\"";
 wifiConfiguration.preSharedKey = "\""+ passwordField.getText().toString() +"\"";

 int netId = wifiManager.addNetwork(wifiConfiguration);
     if (netId >= 0) {
         wifiManager.disconnect();
         wifiManager.enableNetwork(netId, true);

         myBroadcastReceiver = new MyBroadcastReceiver(connectionsList, wifiManager, 
               emptyListText, ssidField, passwordField);

         ssidField.setText("");
         passwordField.setText("");
     }
```

the code i use in the broadcastReceiver

```
   @Override
   public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) 
               context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
   NetworkInfo networkInfo = 
               connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);

   NetworkInfo.State state = networkInfo.getState();

            // i use logs for testing
            switch (state) {
                case CONNECTING:
                    Log.i(TAG, "CONNECTING");
                    break;
                case CONNECTED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "CONNECTED");
                    break;
                case SUSPENDED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "SUSPENDED");
                    break;
                case DISCONNECTED:
                    Log.i(TAG, "DISCONNECTED");
                    break;
                case DISCONNECTING:
                    Log.i(TAG, "DISCONNECTING");
                    break;
            }
  }
```

How can i got a feedback when the phone connect to wifi that i enter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Refer to this. [How to use SUPPLICANT_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION WiFi BroadcastReceiver - android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8847818/how-to-use-supplicant-state-changed-action-wifi-broadcastreceiver-android) and this too https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/SupplicantState.

Comment: Thank you. Can you answer one more question?

Comment: If the password is saved and i am trying to connect to this network by entering a wrong password, it is automatically connects to the wifi with the saved wrong password. For example, the first time i enter the correct password ("12345678"). The second time if i enter a wrong or a correct password it doesn't matter, connects automatically to the wifi. How can i handle this?

Comment: Android API allows the developer to add multiple WifiConfiguration's with the same SSID. The solution would be to search saved WifiConfiguration list from the WifiManager object, and delete all the configs with the same SSID and/or BSSID as the config you want to modify. After this, add your config with a different password.